# How to encapsulate access to similar external libraries within a single application?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependencies

I have an application which we intend to makes use of an external library.  This external library is one of many that provides the same (or similar) functionality.

Take a zip library as an example, there are many libraries out there that does basically the same thing, extract and compress zip files.

However, each library will implement their public classes / interface slightly differently from one another, even if the internal compression algorithm is the same e.g

```
namespace AmazingZipLibrary
{
    public class Archive
    {
        public Zip Add()
        {
          //Create a zip file
        }
    }
}

namespace YetAnotherAmazingZipLibrary
{
    public class Zip
    {
        public object Compress()
        {
          //create a zip file
        }
    }
}
```

How can one make use of libraries interchangeably without breaking the main application each time we want to swap or use another library?  I think the main reason for such requirements is for evaluation and testing purposes.  But it's also possible that a new bad ass zip library comes along that we want to adopt (hypothetically speaking).

What design patterns can help with this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own interface with the required methods.

Implement this interface for each library, wrapping the library functionality with your calls.

```
interface ICompress
{
  void Create();
}

public class AmazingCompressor : ICompress
{
   public void Create()
   {
      // Call AmazingZipLibrary.Add
   }
}

public class YetAnotherAmazingCompressor : ICompress
{
   public void Create()
   {
      // Call YetAnotherAmazingZipLibrary.Compress
   }
}
```

In your code, only refer to `ICompress`.

This is known as the [bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).

Comment: Using the generic interface seems nice but then i would need to modify the source of each lib to implement the interface?  Can the bridge pattern be used with lets say a factory so there's another level of abstraction?

Comment: @Fixer - No need to modify the libraries. You can use an instance of a library and delegate to it. Think composition.

Comment: @Oded , What's the difference with the facade pattern ?

Comment: @remibourgarel - They are very similar. A facade would be put in front of a complex API to make a simple API. A bridge is there to allow one to work consistently with several _different_ APIs.

Answer (score 2):

[Bridge design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) would be a good choice.